# Некорректная работы программы из автозапуска

Tags: python, pyinstaller, pyautogui

Суть в том, что есть скрипт, который делает скриншот экрана по запросу из вне. Программу компилирую через pyinstaller, затем добавляю exe в автозагрузку. После перезагрузки программа запускается на фоне, однако скриншоты уже не делает. Скриншот делаю через pyautogui. Как можно с этим бороться?

Упрощённый пример кода.

```
import os
import sys
import time
import pyautogui
from winreg import *

ROOT_PATH = os.path.dirname(__file__)
PROGRAM_PATH = sys.executable


def test():
    """Делает скрин раз в 60s"""

    while True:
        stamp = round(datetime.timestamp(datetime.now()))
        image_name = f'screen__{met}.jpg'
        path = os.path.join(ROOT_PATH, image_name)
        pyautogui.screenshot(path)
        time.sleep(60)


def add_reg():
    """Добавляет в реестр"""

    program_name = 'Program'
    my_key = OpenKey(
        HKEY_CURRENT_USER,
        r'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run',
        0,
        KEY_ALL_ACCESS
    )
    SetValueEx(my_key, program_name, 0, REG_SZ, PROGRAM_PATH)
    CloseKey(my_key)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    add_reg()
    test()
```

Comment: Без примера кода, скорее всего. никто не угадает, что у вас в программе происходит

Comment: @SergBocharov обновил.

Comment: а вы `test` вызываете?

Comment: @timur конечно. Это я просто пример показал. Суть в том, что если ручками запускать .exe - всё работает отлично. Но если этот же .exe запускается сам, из автозапуска - не работает. Не работает конкретно pyautogui

Comment: Если бы вы запускали на линукс, можно было бы припустить, что у юзера под каким не запускается недостаточно прав для запуска. Это единственное решение раз вручную длает скрин. а через автозагрузку нет. может его нужно запускать с правами супер админа?